# Fetch users from Active Directory using LDAPS in java

Tags: java, ldap

How to fetch users from Active Directory using **LDAPS** in java. The AD server is with our client. I'm able to fetch using LDAP protocol, but for LDAPS what additional information do I require from client?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: [Connecting LDAP server from java application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2880968/connecting-ldap-server-from-java-application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We put up a sample of [connecting to LDAPS with JNDI](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Using%20LDAPS%20With%20JNDI).

We also have some general information on [Using LDAP with AD](http://ldapwiki.willeke.com/wiki/LDAP%20and%20Active%20Directory).
-jim

Answer (score 2):

If you have the AD modules, you can use Get-AD user with the -LDAP Filter clause. You don't need the clauses to restrict the query to users. You can fetch it just check in your AD modules.

Answer (score 0):

The code is quite similar to retrieval of objects from LDAP. 
You need to remember that the port of LDAPS is usually not 389 
 (but that's the easy part) and handle certificate issues, as explained in the following [blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/marginNotes/entry/basic_ssl_ldap_access_with).