# Connect to LDAP server without hardcoding credentials

Tags: java, ldap

In my application i need to connect to `LDAP` server. I am able to connect to the server by hard-coding the password, but i don't want to hard-code the credentials. Please help me in this.

I tried googling, but wasn't able to find how to connect without hard-coding my credentials.

Comment: Is this a pure LDAP or Active Directory server that you are connecting to?

Answer (score 1):

Possible help to you:
[Connecting LDAP server from java application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2880968/connecting-ldap-server-from-java-application?rq=1)

You can update your applications' preferences dynamically, I suppose.

Comment: In this example they have read the crediantials from property file. Is there any way in java, so that i can read it dynamically from the WAS authentication i use?

Comment: That's a pity, but I know nothing about WAS authentification, so maybe I'm saying obvious things. If you can get some kind of a string with your authentification parameters, you can parse it by regex creating HashMap for example. After that you can get your pass: myHashMap.get("password");

Comment: @xvar You can't get your password from Windows, or any other sanely designed security system either.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can use kerberos infrastructure using [GSS-API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/ldap/security/gssapi.html) in Java, since we do this a lot with shell scripts and so.