# garbage character showing due to encoding mismatch

Tags: java, encoding, io, character-encoding, ldap

I am facing a problem in which when I am writing a stream of bytes to a text file one of the characters is showing as Corrupted like this (the ugly question mark)- Ingenier�a. I am getting this byte of stream from an LDAP server. I am using Netscape's ldapsdk-4.1 library to connect to the LDAP server. While debugging I found out that for the corrupted character BufferedInputStream.read() returns 237 and the ldapsdk library is trying to convert it into a byte, like this

```
m_value[i] = (byte) stream.read();        //class BEROctetString:152
```

and that's where the byte value overflows to to -19.

My question is, How can I fix this so that I get correct character value ? or do I need to change the source encoding to single byte ones like ASCII or UTF-8 ? Please suggest if there is any other way of fixing it.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

I am performing a LDAP search and internally the search results are retrieved in the form of bytes using using SocketInputStream.

How can I retrieve the original search results, without any corrupted character, from the array of the bytes I received?

Edit:

As suggested by JohnBollinger in the comments, I dumped the bytes to .txt file as is and opened the file in notepad++ and it displayed all the characters correctly. From notepad++ I checked the file encoding and it was ANSI(aka Cp1252). I wrote a small program to verify it programmatically and it worked. here is the method-

```
private static void bingoWithCpEncoding() throws IOException {
    byte[] byt3 = { 73, 110, 103, 101, 110, 105, 101, 114, -19, 97 };
    ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    buffer.write(byt3);
    String text = buffer.toString("Cp1252"); // UTF-8 was not working
    System.out.print(text);
}
```

it prints "Ingeniería". I copied the byte array while code debugging.

netscape ldapsdk's LDAPAttribute class was trying to encode these bytes in to UTF-8.

```
//
    public Enumeration getStringValues() {
        Vector v = new Vector();
        synchronized(this) {
            try {
                for (int i=0; i<values.length; i++) {
                    if ( values[i] != null ) {
                        v.addElement(new String ((byte[])values[i], "UTF8"));
                    } else {
                        v.addElement( new String( "" ) );
                    }
                }
            } catch ( Exception e ) {
                return null;
            }
        }
        return v.elements();
    }
```

Comment: Yes you probably need to use an 7/8 bit encoding as that letter takes two bytes in UTF-8. ```String iAcute = new String(new byte[] { (byte)237 }, "ISO-8859-1");```

Comment: (Which is of course the same as) ```String iAcute = new String(new byte[] { -19 }, "ISO-8859-1");``` But it's probably not such a good idea to guess the encoding like I did or other characters might not be what you expect

Comment: "*I am writing a stream of bytes to a text file*" -- well there's your problem right there.  Or at least *a* problem.  Bytes should go to a binary file.  If you want to write *text* then you need to handle encoding appropriately.  If you want the resulting file to be byte-for-byte identical to the data retrieved from LDAP then avoid converting the bytes to characters and just dump them as received.

Comment: And it's possible that your program is already doing that just fine, but whatever you're using to view the result is assuming the wrong encoding.  That could be interpreted as the resulting binary file not conforming to the text conventions of your system (*i.e.* back to binary *vs.* text).

Comment: I missed this: *...to single byte ones like ASCII or UTF-8 ?* UTF-8 is *not* a single-byte encoding. It has a variable number of bytes. 'Regular' letters and symbols might be one byte in UTF-8 but not all.

Comment: @JohnBollinger you are right but this byte conversion is happening inside the library, I can't do much about it. The library is also not supported any more. Is there any other library to connect to LDAP without JNDI ?

Comment: Which "conversion" are you referring to? There actually *is* no conversion. What is happening is that *you* are *interpreting* it as a character.

Comment: @AlokMishra, the code excerpt presented in the question is not itself problematic in any way.  Bytes are being read from an `InputStream` and stored in an array of `byte`s.  The cast reflects some technical details of `InputStream`s, and does not corrupt the data.  In particular, converting the `int` value of 237 to a `byte` value of -19 is the normal and expected behavior in such a case.

Comment: "*do I need to change the source encoding to single byte ones like ASCII or UTF-8*?" - unless you instruct it otherwise, the Netscape LDAP SDK will assume that character data exchanged with the server should be / will be encoded in UTF-8.  It looks like that expectation is not being fulfilled in your case. There is probably a way to configure your LDAP connection to request that specifically, but I am not familiar enough with this 20-year-old API to give you detailed recommendations. I think these are the docs: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/816-5618-10/netscape/ldap/package-summary.html

Comment: @g00se I was referring to int to byte conversion which is happening inside the library. This byte array is then passed to String,  new String(byte[], Charset) , this is where the overflown byte value -19 (int =237) is not being interpreted by String. Can we restore 237 from -19 ?

Comment: The byte value -19 *is* 237.  They are *exactly the same bits.*  Whether a value is considered signed or unsigned is simply a matter of how the raw value is interpreted.  [Hint:  what is 256 + (−19)?]  `m_value` is completely correct.  The problem here, as others have said, is that you are viewing your file using the wrong charset.

Comment: Yes. I thought I'd already demonstrated that ;)

Comment: @g00se `new String(new byte[] { (byte)237 }, "ISO-8859-1")` this is printing � on the console. Tried with UTF-8, UTF-16 ASCII as well, same result.

Comment: What OS and what does ```java -version``` give?

Comment: Your 'bingo..' is essentially no different from the code I gave, where you responded *this is printing � on the console. Tried with UTF-8, UTF-16 ASCII as well, same result.* The fact that you used Cp1252 where I used ISO-8859-1 is immaterial as the encoding is identical in each

Comment: It might have been my mistake, it was late night :-) when I ran your code. `new String(new byte[] { (byte)237 }, "ISO-8859-1")` prints í.